How to remove duplication of loguru logger patching in pytest
I am testing a function which calls loguru.logger.add("file.log") at the start. This causes issues during pytest execution. The file is written to a temp dir and thus is being used by another process (good ol' Windows) when clean-up happens.
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'path/to/tmp_dir/file.log'

One solution is to patch loguru.logger.add on each test. But this results in much repeated (boilerplate?) code. For many tests, I don't need to refer to logger.add,  just need patch it so the test runs.
@patch("loguru.logger.add")
def test_one(mock_logger_add):
    ...
    # Useful to check, but don't want to call this in EVERY test
    mock_logger_add.assert_called_once()

@patch("loguru.logger.add")
def test_two(mock_logger_add):
    ...
    # No need to check mock_logger_add, just want my code to run


How can I reduce this duplication?
Things I've tried:

Adding an autouse=True fixture to conftest.py or in the test file/class

e.g.
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_logger_add(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("loguru.logger.add", lambda *args, **kwargs: None)
    # or
    # monkeypatch.setattr("loguru.logger.add", MagicMock())

or
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def no_logger_add(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.delattr("loguru.logger.add")

These don't work. Perhaps because, in order for loguru to work with pytest, we have to redefine caplog and that involves calling logger.add.
Note: I do not want to turn loguru off completely because I check the logs for errors in my tests.
Minimal reproducible example
compute_statistics.py
from loguru import logger

class ExampleClass:

    def compute(self):
        logger.add("0_example.log")
        logger.info("Starting to compute")
        logger.success("Finished computing")
        return "Done"

conftest.py
import pytest
from loguru import logger
from _pytest.logging import LogCaptureFixture

@pytest.fixture
def caplog(caplog: LogCaptureFixture):
    handler_id = logger.add(
        caplog.handler,
        format="{message}",
        level=0,
        filter=lambda record: record["level"].no >= caplog.handler.level,
        enqueue=False,  # Set to 'True' if your test is spawning child processes.
    )
    yield caplog
    logger.remove(handler_id)

test_compute_statistics.py
import logging
import pytest
from compute_statistics import ExampleClass
from unittest.mock import patch

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_logger_add():
    with patch("compute_statistics.logger.add"):
        yield

def assert_no_errors_logged(caplog):
    error_messages = [record for record in caplog.records if record.levelno >= logging.ERROR]
    num_errors = len(error_messages)
    assert num_errors == 0


def test_example_class(caplog):
    ex = ExampleClass()
    result = ex.compute()
    assert result == "Done"
    assert_no_errors_logged(caplog)


Since you say the patch decorator works but monkeypatch seemingly is not, I'm curious whether using patch as a context manager from within the fixture may solve your issue?
Example
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_logger(caplog):
    with patch("your_module.logger.add"):
        yield


This works if I do not pass caplog to my tests. But fails on teardown if I do. We redefine caplog and it uses logger.add which breaks things

This makes me think perhapspatch_logger is being executed before the caplog redefinition. I updated my answer -- but can you try supplying caplog as an argument to patch_logger? This should ensure the correct order.

Still doesn't work unfortunately. I tried defining patch_loger above and below caplog in conftest but doesn't change anything. Also, logger.add is still being executed (and the log file still being created) so I don't think autouse=True is actually patching it

The definition order in the conftest file should not matter. Pytest can not guarantee the fixture call order unless we chain them together which we did by supplying caplog as an argument. This works correctly in a basic example I recreated on my machine and the log file is never generated.

However since the file is still being generated, I'm thinking the patch is incorrect. Try patching where logger is imported and utilized, not defined. For example your_module.logger.add

I've added a minimal reproducible example to the question which fails on my machine. Can you try that? Hopefully it's obvious to you now what is going wrong! Patching compute_statistics.logger.add didn't help, failed on teardown of caplog as it is patching logger.add within the caplog fixture for some reason.

When I run the example, it's failing with a traceback referencing logger.remove. This is because the patch is still applied during teardown. Your example is missing patch_logger_add(caplog) which I spoke about previously. Even though we're not using caplog within that fixture, by supplying it as an argument we're ensuring the patch is applied after caplog setup and removed before the teardown.

Amazing! Yes that worked. I also had to modify another part of code (not included in the example above) which was confusing me. Thanks for all your help.
